# How to store multiple string values into one string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc

I'm a newbie in C so please excuse some of my mistakes.
I'm wondering if there is a possible way to store multiple string/array values in one string? Here is an example to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const char *lister[] = {"H", "E", "LL", "O"}; //forgot brackets, fixed now

int main()
{
    char *mystring[] = ("%s%s", lister[1], lister[2]);
    printf ("%s\n", mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if that makes any sense at all, but looking for ways to store string values into another string or array.
Thanks! :)    EDIT: strncat fixes this problem, if you encountered the same problem then go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncat.htm to learn more, thanks to computerfreaker for suggesting strncat!

Comment: You can look into `strcat` or `strncat`. Both functions append (conCATenate) one string to another. `strcat` appends one entire string to another; `strncat` is slightly safer because you specify the number of characters from the second string to append to the first.

Comment: The mystring part won't work - use strcpy and strcat to copy and contatenate strings.  Make sure you allocate a buffer first.

Comment: @computerfreaker you should probably make your comment an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @Mauren Done. Thanks for flagging me, I wouldn't have realized op opted to work with my suggestion otherwise!

Comment: `char multistring[] = "one\0two\0three"; printf("%s, %s, %s\n", multistring, multistring + 4, multistring + 8);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sprintf for coping multiple string to one string with your own format also.

```
sprintf(destination_string, "%s----%s", source_string1,source_string2);
```

Comment: Splendid, seems like the shortest and most readable way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a pair of square brackets:

```
const char *lister[] = {"H", "E", "LL", "O"};
//                ^^
//               Here
```

To put several strings into one with a format string you can use `sprintf`, like this:

```
// Prepare the buffer for the output
char buf[100];
// The format string and parameters come from your code.
sprintf(buf, "%s%s", lister[1], lister[2]);
```

Note that your program would produce the values of the second and the third string, because the initial index in a C array is zero, not one.

Answer (score 2):

This `const char *lister = {"H", "E", "LL", "O"};` should be either this:

```
const char **lister = {"H", "E", "LL", "O"};
```

or

```
const char *lister[] = {"H", "E", "LL", "O"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) or [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/). Both functions append (conCATenate) one string to another.

`strcat` appends one entire string to another; you're required to make sure the destination buffer is big enough to hold both strings as well as a trailing null character (`\0`).

`strncat` is slightly safer because you specify the number of characters from the second string to append to the first, which means you can always be sure your buffer is big enough to hold everything you need it to.